# Bitrise build fails for Android 13 (API level 33)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, cicd, bitrise, android-13

Bitrise fails to build an Android app which targets Android 13 (API level 33).

I've checked on Bitrise stacks and android-33 is only present in linux-docker-android-20.04 stack. This is unsuitable for me as I develop cross-platform app and use the other stack which depends on macOS.

Is there any command which can be used in bitrise.yaml to install Android 33 API? I tried to find Bitrise guides on this case but found none.

Here is the the error from Bitrise:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(100,5): error XA5207: Could not find android.jar for API level 33. This means the Android SDK platform for API level 33 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...), or change the Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed. (/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platforms/android-33/android.jar missing.)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a way around this? I tried using `android-sdk-update` to install SDK version 33 but the cordova build step still only sees v32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `android-sdk-update` step uses the [deprecated sdk-tools](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/sdk-tools) from the [/tools/ folder](https://github.com/guitcastro/steps-update-sdk/blob/fb76af2d0e6137bc09b7c432ce22d119d1f9e754/step.sh#L45) which require Java 8 to run. Presumably the default Java Version on your Bitrise machine is 11. My solution was:

1. Set Java version to 8
2. Install build-tools 33.0.2 (via the android-sdk-update step)
3. Set Java version to 17 (or whatever version you need)

[image: Bitrise workflow in order to install Android build-tools 33.0.2]

It seems hacky but since the `android-sdk-update` step hasn't been updated for more than 6 years, I'm just glad it somehow works.